# How can I validate the data calculated on the basis of associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I  have a posts model which has_one reposts  and  has_one  sponsored. User can  purchase reposts  and  sponsored posts while creating a  post. I want that the minimum purchase(sum of reposts and sponsored purchases) be atleast  1$. so  i want  to  validate  this  in the post model but i  can't  figure out on  how  to write such  a  validation rule. Here is  my  post model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :repost
  has_one :sponsor
```

Any help is more than appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom validator... this is just to give you a basic idea, since I have no idea what your model attributes actually are.

```
validate :minimum_purchase

protected

def minimum_purchase
  unless ((self.repost.try(:purchase).to_i + self.sponsor.try(:purchase).to_i) == 100)
    self.errors.add_to_base("You need to purchase at least $1!")
  end
end
```

Comment: But the  data  for  the  purchase  and  sponsor is not in the  posts  object ..  The  data  comes like  this:

{
[:post]=>{id="5",
[:repost]=>{purchase="30"},
[:sponsor]=>{purchase=>"80"}
}}

Comment: Updated to reflect this.  Assuming your purchase attribute is cents.